# собрать Array со значениями из массива с несколькими NSDictionary

Tags: массивы, swift

Привет.
У меня есть массив, который хранит несколько nsDictionary (их бывает разное кол-во), выглядит так:

```
[{
    BTmac = "123";
    DeviceModel = "BBB";
    DeviceType = 1;
    ID = 1;
    ST = 3;
}, {
    BTmac = "123";
    DeviceModel = "BBB";
    DeviceType = 1;
    ID = 2;
    ST = 5;
}, {
    BTmac = "123";
    DeviceModel = "NNN";
    DeviceType = 0;
    ID = 3;
    ST = 5;
}]
```

Мне нужно собрать в отдельные два массива значения ключа **ID** из всех дикшинари (их может быть разное кол-во, как 1 так и 100), если `DeviceType = 1`, то в первый массив, если `DeviceType = 0` то во второй, что бы было так: `first = [1,2]` `second = [3]`

Спасибо.

Comment: что пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko написал цикл for in, который стыдно показывать, не могу сообразить как воссоздать нужную конструкцию, либо вообще нужен другой подход..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let sourceArray = [[
    "BTmac" : "123",
    "DeviceModel" : "BBB",
    "DeviceType" : "1",
    "ID" : "1",
    "ST" : "3"
    ], [
        "BTmac" : "123",
        "DeviceModel" : "BBB",
        "DeviceType" : "1",
        "ID" : "2",
        "ST" : "5"
    ], [
        "BTmac" : "123",
        "DeviceModel" : "NNN",
        "DeviceType" : "0",
        "ID" : "3",
        "ST" : "5"
    ]]

var firstArray:Array = [Int]()
var secondArray:Array = [Int]()
for (_, element) in sourceArray.enumerated() {
    if(Int(element["DeviceType"]!)! == 1) {
        firstArray.append(Int(element["ID"]!)!)
    } else {
        secondArray.append(Int(element["ID"]!)!)
    }
}
print(firstArray)
print(secondArray)
```

Comment: Ваш вариант великолепно работает, строка с append была переписана таким образом ` firstArray.append(element["ID"]! as! Int)`, иначе ругался.
Не могу понять почему к теме прилетел дизлайк..